# Cosa significa “piccola gente” in questa frase?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel libro *Sardegna come un'infanzia* di Elio Vittorini ho letto:

> È prestissimo, a giudicare dai negozi tutti chiusi. Passa *piccola gente* frettolosa e uno in maniche di camicia lancia acqua con un secchio, violentemente, contro il marciapiede. Poi spazza e tira fuori dei tavolini.

Secondo il [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/piccolo1/), l'aggettivo *piccolo* significa

> In genere, inferiore alla misura ordinaria, in senso proprio o figurato.
>
> **a.** Con riguardo alle dimensioni, alla grandezza: *una casa p., un p. giardino; un p. tavolo; un p. quadro; un p. libro, o un libro p.; una p. automobile; mani p., piedi p.; un paio di scarpe troppo piccole per lui;* [...] Riferito a persona (per lo più posposto), può indicarne l’altezza, la statura: *un uomo p.; una donna p. ma ben proporzionata*; talvolta anche raddoppiato: *una donna piccola piccola* (e fig., *farsi piccolo piccolo*, cercare di non farsi notare tra altri, di passare inosservato); precisando: *essere p. di statura, p. di persona*; oppure può indicare l’età: *ha due figli p., ancora p.; sei p., non puoi capire queste cose; è troppo p. per andare ai giardini da solo*.
>
> **c.** Rispetto alla quantità: *solo una p. parte dei presenti ha votato la mozione; raccogliere un p. numero di adesioni; ne ho ricavato un p. guadagno*.

La mia domanda è: qual è il significato di "piccola gente" nel testo precedente? Gente di piccola statura? Poca gente? O si tratta forse di bambini?

Comment: Direi che *poca gente* è il significato della frase.

Comment: La mia impressione (che non saprei come suffragare con prove) è che sia un misto di “poca gente” e di quegli usi linguistici a cui appartengono “omino” (“è passato l'omino del gas”) e simili.

Comment: Mi pare però che _piccolo_ per _poco_ si possa usare se il sostantivo a cui si riferisce denota un oggetto (piú o meno) definito, delimitato. _Piccola folla_, _piccolo gruppo_, _piccola parte_ sono espressioni corrette. _Piccola gente_ non attiva quest’interpretazione di _piccolo_, secondo quel che pare a me: _piccolo_ lo avverto come un aggettivo figurato (sull’esempio di _minuto_ in [_popolo minuto_](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/minuto1/) in opposizione a _popolo grasso_), anche per la posizione presostantivale.

Answer (score 1):

Lì 'piccola gente' - considerato il contesto - significa 'popolino', che è, come recita il Treccani, la 'parte del popolo meno progredita culturalmente e socialmente'.

È plausibile che l'autore preferisca usare 'piccola gente' per evitare il senso spregiativo di 'popolino' (in modo simile a come lo fa Guareschi nel suo *Mondo piccolo*).

Comment: Strani questi due silenti downvoti, molto strani.

Comment: Tenendo conto del tono rispettoso di tutto il libro di Vittorini, del modo in cui descrive i contadini per esempio, neanch'io penso che questa sia la risposta.

Comment: @Charo A esser sincero, quest’interpretazione era venuta in mente anche a me. Bisognerebbe avere un po’ di contesto in piú. In ogni caso, la benevolenza o la vicinanza verso un gruppo sociale non esclude l’uso di una definizione come questa, che a parer mio non è necessariamente negativa o spregiativa.

Comment: Non vedo come piccola gente possa considerarsi spregiativo. Guareschi usa il termine `piccolo` riferendosi al suo Mondo Piccolo, fatto di gente semplice, laboriosa, di bassa estrazione culturale ma colma di saggezza popolare. Per me nessun downvote, ma anzi un upvote.

Comment: @RiccardoI.: Non sono sicuro di seguirti. Siamo d'accordo che “piccola gente” non è spregiativo, mentre la parola “popolino” lo ha eccome, un connotato negativo.

Comment: Hai ragione non ho pensato a popolino e mi sono concentrato solo su `gente piccola`. Che poi in realtà anche gente piccola ha assunto un connotato negativo negli ultimi anni (Che persona piccola che sei) ma dubito fosse questo il senso sia per Guareschi, sia per Vittorini.

Comment: Penso che qui *piccolo* abbia anche  la connotazione di  *poco importante, nel senso di gente comune* che non ha nulla a che vedere con il significato chiaramente spregiativo di *popolino*.

Comment: @FerdinandBardamu: Non c'è molto contesto da aggiungere. Vittorini ha fatto un viaggio in Sardegna. In quel momento è in un albergo a Sassari. Si è svegliato presto la mattina e descrive quello che vede dalla finestra.

Comment: @Charo Capisco, grazie. In ogni caso perché l’aggettivo significhi «poca» è necessario, a mio parere, che sia applicato, come dicevo su, a un oggetto delimitato nello spazio. _Piccola folla_ e _piccolo gruppo_ vanno bene in questo caso, ma _piccola gente_ può essere interpretato o come «gente umile» o come «gente di bassa statura». Ma questa seconda accezione sarebbe meglio espressa con «gente piccola», perché l’aggettivo preposto al nome — in posizione marcata — assume in molti casi una connotazione figurata.

Comment: Se ho capito bene i vostri commenti, "piccola gente" può avere un significato un po' simile a "popolino", ma senza la connotazione negativa che ha quest'ultimo vocabolo. È così?

Comment: @Charo Esatto. È proprio così. L'autore ha preferito 'piccola gente' proprio per evitare il senso spregiativo di 'popolino', sebbene la connotazione negativa resti.

Comment: @Charo Grazie mille per l'edit. L'ho solo modificato un po' perché l' "abbia" non ci stava. Poi ho sostituito 'probabilmente' con 'plausibilmente' perché, in questo caso, lo preferisco.